# Grade 8 Random Number Question - Which concept to use

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables

I found a question in Math Challengers 2012 exam (Provencial, part2, Q8). It states

> Betty and Ben each select independently and at random an integer between 0 and 5 (inclusive). What is the average non-negative difference between their numbers? Express the answer as a common fraction.

You get about 2 minutes to do this without a calculator. Which concept do you use? Does this belong to the Combinatorics/Probability Generating Functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always helps to draw a sample space diagram. In the below table, the entries show the difference between Ben and Betty's scores:
\begin{array}{cc|ccccc}
& & & & \mbox{Ben} \\
&  & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
\hline
& 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
& 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\mbox{Betty} & 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
& 3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
& 4 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
& 5 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
Since the outcomes are equiprobable, we know that the average distance is
$$
\frac{\text{Sum of differences}}{\text{No. of outcomes}}=\frac{70}{36}=\frac{35}{18} \, .
$$
I found that it was possible to add up each row in my head, and also use the symmetries of the question to make the calculation easier. Notice how the rows sum to $15$, $11$, $9$, $9$, $11$, $15$; this happens because it is just as likely for Ben to get the number $x$ and Betty to get $y$ as it is for Betty to get $x$ and Ben to get $y$.

Answer (score 3):

you have to calculate

$$\mathbb{E}|X-Y|=1\times \frac{10}{36}+2\times \frac{8}{36}+3\times \frac{6}{36}+4\times \frac{4}{36}+5\times \frac{2}{36}=\frac{70}{36}$$

the fastest manual way is to write down a $6\times6$ table, remembering that any outcome is equiprobable

Comment: @paw88789 thanks:(...as requested I did it without calculator and I did $4\times4=8$

Comment: Thanks.  So there are 10 ways of getting a difference of 1, 8 ways of getting a difference of 2 and so on. I can calculate it after looking at the 6x6 table done by Joe, but is there any direct way of calculating this to save precious time during the exam?

Comment: @NickP I did visualize the matrix by mind...after a little practice this is natural. I did the execise in 1'47'' (with a minor calculation error)